# jquery mobile data-transition not working

Tags: jquery, transition

Im trying to create a button with an data-transition but is not working.
Here is my code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jq/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
<script src="jq/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="jq/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<a href="pelis.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-inline="true">dialog</a>
```

When i click on the button, the effect is not working...
What im doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you using IE9 to test?  I was pulling my hair out until I figured out IE9 couldn't do transitions.  When I switched to chrome, the transitions worked.